# what is the adjective of relation pertaining to computer programs?

Tags: adjectives

If you have an npm library (a piece of software program, a chunk of computer code) as a noun, how would you turn it into an *adjective of relation*?

Something like "softwarian" or "programmarian", just a real word?

Comment: Relation _to what_? Can you give an example sentence showing how you intend to use your word?

Comment: For example, if you want to say in a fancy way that an npm library was resuscitated, you would say "npm-librarian resuscitation" happened. Except "npm-librarian" should be a real word. We need something like "pulmonic resuscitation", just for pieces of software.

Comment: I think I'd stick with 'We performed a resuscitation of an (the) npm library'.

Comment: Better provide an example sentence to help us help you.

Comment: can't you just use 'she'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, software naming doesn't allow for simple adjectivization. I currently can't think of any example (in a software context) where an adjective (based on a noun) is used.

Instead, it is much more idiomatic to use the noun attributively, also known as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), emphasis mine:

> It is a trait of natural language that there is often more than one way to say something. Any logically valid option will usually find some currency in natural usage. Thus "erythrocyte maturation" and "erythrocytic maturation" can both be heard, the first using a noun adjunct and the second using an adjectival inflection. **In some cases one of the equivalent forms has greater idiomaticness; thus "cell cycle" is more commonly used than "cellular cycle"**.

The emphasized part is relevant to your question. **When referring to programming terms, the noun adjunct is more idiomatic in the majority of cases**, and arguably the default approach to modifying a noun.

The linked page also contains a few examples where there is a meaningful distinction between the noun adjuct and the adjectival inflection:

> - In some cases, each form tends to adhere to a certain sense; thus "face mask" is the normal term in hockey, and "facial mask" is heard more often in spa treatments.
> - Although "spine cord" is not an idiomatic alternative to "spinal cord", in other cases, the options are arbitrarily interchangeable with negligible idiomatic difference; thus "spine injury" and "spinal injury" coexist and are equivalent from any practical viewpoint, ...
> - ... as are "meniscus transplant" and "meniscal transplant".
> - A special case in medical usage is "visual examination" versus "vision examination": the first typically means "an examination made visually", whereas the latter means "an examination of the patient's vision".

Notice how common it is for software development:

- The **code** quality (instead of the possessive)
- The **npm library** installation (instead of an adjective or possessive)
- The **Visual Studio** debugger (instead of the possessive)
- The **interface** implementation (instead of an adjective or possessive)

Constructions like "the *interfacial* implementation" or "the *code's* quality" are *technically correct* (going by general English grammar), but sound non-idiomatic in a programming context.

---

If you want to avoid using noun adjuncts (because you're creating a long chain of adjuncts, or to avoid a contextual ambiguity), then I suggest you stick to the more verbose possessive:

- The quality **of the code**
- The installation **of the npm library**
- The implementation **of the interface(s)**